# Will OpenGL ever generate a texture-\framebuffer-\shader- etc ID whose value is 0?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Will the id's generated by `glGenTextures(...)`, `glGenFramebuffers(...)` ever be 0? 
To be more specific, can I use zero as the id for a uninitialized texture, or do I need to use -1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do I need to use -1?

You can't use -1, because object names are *unsigned* integers.

> Will the id's generated by glGenTextures(...), glGenFramebuffers(...) ever be 0?

No.

> To be more specific, can I use zero as the id for a uninitialized texture

For *textures*, yes.

For *most* [OpenGL objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object), object 0 is equivalent to a NULL pointer: it isn't an object. However, for *some* OpenGL objects, [object 0 does have meaning](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_zero).

Framebuffer object 0, for example, is the default framebuffer. And technically, texture object 0 is still a texture. However, the behavior of texture object 0 is so oddball that it's best to completely ignore this and just never explicitly use texture object 0.

Answer (score 6):

No `glGen*` function ever returns 0, although sometimes it refers to a default object.In the case of textures, you can find the appropriate information in the documentation of [glDeleteTextures](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml). In this case 0 is the default texture, which is never returned by `glGenTextures`.